# Cannot delete apps from Fabric because there are too many?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I am a Android developer and I had clients building their apps with my source and by doing that caused my fabric apps to grow quite large. Right now I have 1167 apps under my organization and i'm trying to clean them up.

the problem is whenever i click on apps i just get a loading screen and they never show up. I have left the site up for hours and never loads.

I really don't want to delete this account because it uses my main email i develop with and I also have apps in this organization that i monitor daily.

So how can I consolidate these 1167 apps down to just a few?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. It wouldn't surprise me if you're hitting a timeout while we try to load all of the details for all of your apps. Email support(at)fabric(dot)io with the bundle id or package names that you do care about and we can remove the ones you don't need. Feel free to ask for me personally in that email.